# Showing custom field contents without listing description

Tags: php, custom-field, customization, themes

I'm customizing a directory theme and my custom fields appear only if I put some text at the company's description, otherwise it will show nothing...

Any idea how to fix that??

I think the problem should be here...

```
<div class="company-content-container container-16">
<div class="company-tabs-single-company block">
<div class="block-title">
</div>

    <div class="company-info clearfix" >

        <div class="company-info-description" <?php if(!$item_soc_fb AND !$item_soc_tw AND  !$item_soc_gp){echo 'style="margin-left: 180px"';} ?>>
            <div class="breadcrumbs"></div>
</div>
</div>
  </div>
   <?php if( get_the_content() ):?><h3>
<?php

echo types_render_field("nome-do-aeroporto", array("argument1"=>"value1","argument2"=>"value2","argument2"=>"value2"));

?>
<br/>
<?php

echo types_render_field("cidade", array("argument1"=>"value1","argument2"=>"value2","argument2"=>"value2"));

?>
```

Comment: Can you add some code to your question? Without a frame of reference it's extremely hard to debug any issues.

Comment: Just did my friend!.. Sorry... i totally forgot

Answer (score 0):

The reason your custom fields are only showing up when there is post content is due to this line:

```
<?php if( get_the_content() ):?><h3>
```

Everything after that line will only appear if get_the_content() returns something truthy. The reason being that you're using a shorthand if statement and not closing to before the custom field logic Try this:

>

```
<?php if( get_the_content() ):?><h3>
<?php
//this closes the if statment
endif;
?>
<?php
echo types_render_field("nome-do-aeroporto", array("argument1"=>"value1","argument2"=>"value2","argument2"=>"value2"));

?>
<br/>
<?php

echo types_render_field("cidade", array("argument1"=>"value1","argument2"=>"value2","argument2"=>"value2"));

 ?>
```

I am wondering why your using that if statement in the first place however.

Hope this helps

Comment: I bought this theme, and that's how it came... I'm not a programmer..im trying to fix some stuff the the little I know and with help from guys like you! I'll try that and let you know... thanks a lot!